# rubymine view html generated by erb rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

Is it possible to see the html generated by html.erb files within RubyMine? I know that I have been able to see the css.min generated by css, so there must be a similar option to be able to see the direct html generated by embedded ruby?

Answer (score 0):

With your Rails server running you can right click a view template file in the project tree and select `open in browser`

But this is essentially the same as visiting `localhost:3000/posts` manually, e.g.

Rubymine can't render the view and make the necessary calls to the controller actions and database without the whole app running